# New design: "Ask question" overlaps background

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I'm looking at some post, the "ASK QUESTION" text (up-left) overlaps the other text, normally the title of the post.

In Chrome 6.0

Answer (score 1):

fix is coming very soon.

Comment: the fix has been deploy, please verify.

Comment: fixed in FF3

Comment: Still happens for me if I zoom in one time with "zoom text only" turned off (which is how I would usually browse, to make the fonts more readable for my vision). Firefox 3.6.9.

Comment: basically fixed. But, following Carl's comment: the problem reappears in Chrome 6.0 if I zoom out (by Ctrl-Wheel or Zoom->83%)